# Meteor Autoform validateForm ignores unique

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

The method AutoForm.validateForm(formID) returns true although unique is true in SimpleSchema and a duplicate value is entered. Nobody else seems to have this issue so I wonder what I'm doing wrong. This is the full sample code:

**common/collections.js**

```js
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);
const afCollection = {};
Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('afCollection', afCollection);
checkTable = afCollection.checkTable = new Meteor.Collection('checkTable');
// Meteor.isServer && checkTable._dropCollection();

checkTable.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  checkValue: {
    type: String,
    index:true,
    unique:true,
    optional:false
  }
}, { tracker: Tracker }));
```

**client/maintenance.js**

```js
AutoForm.debug();
Template.Maintenance.events({
  'click .save' () {
    if (AutoForm.validateForm("newOne")) {
      $('form#newOne').submit() }
    else {
      console.log("should see error message now")
    };
    console.log("Saved:",checkTable.find().fetch())
  }
});
```

**client/maintenance.html**

```html
<template name="Maintenance">
  <a class='save' href=#>Save</a>
  {{#autoForm id='newOne' type="insert" collection=afCollection.checkTable autosave=false }}
    {{> afQuickField name="checkValue"}}
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

**packages:**

```
aldeed:autoform@6.2.0
aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.4
aldeed:schema-index@2.1.1
```

validateForm works correctly in case of input is empty. In case of unique is violated, validateForm returns true. When you call .submit(), the error message in the template is displayed correctly and you could react on the error using an AutoForm.hook (probably, not tested).

Unfortunately this does not help in my situation, because clicking on "save" will submit several forms at once. I must ensure that all forms are error-free before the first one is submitted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a question on that: does it behave differently, when you set on the `#autoform` the attribute `validation=` to different values, such as `submit` or `submitThenBlur` ?

Comment: Checking uniqueness would normally require a server round-trip since the duplicate record would not necessarily be published to the client. I doubt that autoform has implemented server-side duplicate checking as part of form validation. I would recommend doing this at the field level on a change event.

Comment: @Jankapunkt No difference. I've tested all possible validation values first with an empty input, then with a duplicate input. Empty input reacts according to the documentation, duplicate input causes an error only after submit returned unsuccessful.

Comment: @Michel Floyd I will concentrate on this approach. In the meantime I've received a new request which requires a case insensitive dupe check, so a simple "unique:true" is insufficient anyway.

Comment: See https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#asynchronous-custom-validation-on-the-client - your use case is almost literally an example in the docs.